# Understanding git and checkout

Tags: git, ubuntu, makefile, installation, cmake

I'm trying to understand how git works for when I want to install a library. Let's say I have a library called foo, and it has two versions: `foo-1.0` and `foo-2.0`. So, I run `git clone git://github.com/dartsim/dart.git`, which downloads all the source files. Then, I decide that I want to install version `foo-1.0`. So, I run `git checkout release-1.0`. Then, I create a build directory with `mkdir build`, enter it with `cd build`, and then build and install the library with `cmake ../src` and `make install`.

Ok, so in the `build` folder, there is a library called `libfoo.so.1`. After inspecting my `/usr/local/lib` directory, there is also a copy of `libfoo.so.1` following the installation. I also see the header file `foo.h` has been copied to `/usr/local/include`.

Now, suppose I also want to install `foo-2.0` on the same system, without uninstalling `foo-1.0`. For example, I might have done an update with git, which requires me to recompile and reinstall the latest version.

What would happen in terms of the installed library and header files? I guess that there would be a `foo-2.0` created in the `build` directory, which would also be copied to `/usr/local/lib`. However, what about the header file? It is different between versions 1 and 2, but there is only one copy in the source files. Will running `checkout release-2.0`, `cmake ../src` and `make install` just overwrite the header file at `usr/local/include` with the header file for version 2? In that case, how can I use both versions of the library on the same system?

I'm just generally a little unclear about how `checkout` works and what it actually means in terms of installations.....Any help to clear this up would be great, thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `git` or `cmake`, these are just tools to perform what you tell them to perform.  What you're after is the distinction between shared library **soname** and versioning (major version updates vs. minor version updates).  Good practitioners of software packaging will package the code in a way that you shall be able to build both `foo-1.0` and `foo-2.0` from the master branch by giving different build arguments to `cmake`.  `checkout` shall be used to get a previous **minor** version, never to get a previous **major** version.

Answer (score 1):

git checkout gives you a specific branch. You could have 2 different versions, on 2 branches. Your build system needs to clone a specific branch which you can do with this command

```
git clone -b <branch name> <remote_repo>
```

you will never have 2 versions of the same code in the same place, that makes no sense basically.

when you run the checkout command it will switch to that version of the code in that specific branch.

One note here. The checkout command DOES NOT remove folders which don't exist in the last branch you checkout so you can end up with extra folders.

Typically you do not need to run git checkout as part of your build process. Just clone whatever branch you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how it works with header files. I understand that if I checkout and install the two versions, there will be two libraries installed. However, there is only one header file in the source directory. Will a modified version of this header file be created and installed for each of these versions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be used to a different version control system, like SVN or ClearCase.

Checkout means something entirely different in Git and shouldn't have anything to do with installations or duplicated files. Branches are technically pointers to a commit that becomes the parent to a new line of commits. The files aren't duplicated unless they're currently being working on and changed, and then they exist as objects that are a part of new commits, children of that parent 'branch' commit.

Checking out to a branch wouldn't change the access or versions of any dependencies or headers unless you changed them specifically while checked out to that branch.